# Extending Application class in Android

Tags: variables, global, android

I'm having troubles extending the Application class to declare global variables. I have extended the `Application` class as folows:

```
public class RunKeeper extends Application{     
private String filename = getResources().getString(R.string.filename);  
private Runner runner;      
public RunKeeper(){ } 
}
```

The class above is in the `com.tmeersschaert.android.runkeeper.domain` package. I have edited the application manifest as (I think) it should be:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.tmeersschaert.android.runkeeper"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:name=".domain.RunKeeper" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
</manifest>
```

The problem is that I keep getting a "Source not found", NullPointer exception during the `LoadedApk.makeApplication()` method.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put the line

```
filename = getResources().getString(R.string.filename);
```

in your constructor.

Have you also tried to use the whole package name:

```
<application android:name="com.tmeersschaert.android.runkeeper.domain.RunKeeper" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the getResources()... from the class (didn't work even in constructor) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing .domain. part from android:name property.